# dockerfile COPY not copying file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm creating a dockerFile and trying to copy an environment configuration file that I've at the same path where dockerFile is found. The idea is to copy it during the docker build process to be able to use it during the gradle build a few steps later.

```
RUN \
  set -ex && \
  cd /app/src && \
  git clone URL.git  dest_folder

COPY .env_dev /app/src/dest_folder
```

After that, to check if the file is already there I make a pwd to ensure I'm in the right folder and ls -la to see if the file is there, but it never is, I can only find files downloaded from the repository, but of course, the .env_dev with credentials is not uploaded to the repository.

```
RUN \
  cd /app/src/dest-folder && \
    pwd && \
    ls -la
```

I'm sure it may be something tricky I'm not using correctly but checked with both ADD/COPY with no results. I've even tried to use the wrong filename to see if COPY complains about it, and it does, so ... it seems that COPY finds it.

Comment: Are you using any king of specifics users / permissions for the file or inside the contianer ?

Comment: @SamiTahri not using specific users/permissions AFAIK, the source file is a hidden file under windows10 OS, I think that's the most remarkable thing

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I've tried removing the ./gradlew build that is done after this process, that requires this .env_dev file to finish successfuly. After removing it, the docker image has been created and if I navigate to /app/src/dest_folder I can see the files there. So the problem seems to be that the ./gradlew task is unable to detect it during the docker build process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, finally I managed to see the problem.
It's **quite weird**... I'm cloning my repository to dest-folder, but copying the file in dest_folder.
That's why the file wasn't being detected, because it was in another folder.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `.dockerignore` file, make sure that you do not ignore hidden files like `.git` or `.venv`

more info here :
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file

Comment: Thanks. I don't have a .dockerIgnore file, I do have .gitIgnore and this specific file is ignored at .gitignore but I guess it should mess with it.
In fact I've tried creating a plain text file and it doesn't seem to be copied either way.

Comment: If problem is still there, maybe you can build your environment directly in the docker container using RUN command : 
`RUN pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: There is this statement in the [doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) `Note: For historical reasons, the pattern . is ignored.`